# Bootstrap + Fontawesome + IE7 = no caption on buttons with icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, font-awesome

I have a problem with Bootstrap, Fontawesome and IE7 when using a button group like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="some-url.html" class="btn icon-circle-arrow-left"> Back</a>
    <a href="some-other-url.html" class="btn icon-edit"> Edit</a>
</div>
```

I have included the CSS files in the HEAD of the document (HTML5) as:

```
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/fontawesome/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It shows up as expected in most modern browsers. But in IE7, the caption text on the button disappears. See the attached screenshot (IE7 on WinXP, IE8 on WinXP, Safari on OS X). When using the F12 developer tools on IE8 and running in compatibility mode, I see that the text-node in the  tag only contains a square (the icon that the dev tools cannot display); the text in the node is gone. Changing it manually gets rid of the icon and shows the text.

Does anyone has any suggestions how I can fix this issue? Dropping support on IE7 is not an option unfortunately. It is ok that it looks ugly though.. :-)

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's to be expected because they're using a CSS Expression to generate the content you need due to IE7's lack of `:before`/`:after` support.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css

```
.icon-glass{*zoom:expression(this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1',this.innerHTML = '&#xf000;')}
```

You have to use an empty element in this case:

```
<a href="some-url.html"><span class="btn icon-circle-arrow-left"></span> Back</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried including html5shiv for HTML5 Support in IE 6-8? https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/